# How to create contingency table in r for with multiple columns, sub columns, and statistical test?

Tags: r, dplyr, chi-squared

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(`Column 1` = c(4.6875, 4.35625, 4.62083333333333, 
3.625, 4.125, 4.16666666666667, 4.41071428571429, 3.78125, 4.77083333333333, 
4.90625, 4.75, 3.85, 4, 4.78125, 4.44791666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
3.95833333333333, 4.17916666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.25634920634921
), `Column 2` = c(4.16666666666667, 4.2, 3.38888888888889, 4, 
3.33333333333333, 4.06666666666667, 3.87857142857143, 3.38888888888889, 
4.75, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.58333333333333, 
4.34722222222222, 5, 2.77777777777778, 2.8, 3.54166666666667, 
3.86666666666667, 3.83888888888889), `Column 3` = c(4.42857142857143, 
4.2952380952381, 4.57619047619048, 3.64285714285714, 4, 4.26190476190476, 
3.6421768707483, 3.17857142857143, 4.76190476190476, 4.58333333333333, 
4.85714285714286, 4.22857142857143, 4.14285714285714, 4.53571428571429, 
4.31666666666667, 3.71428571428571, 4.09523809523809, 3.48571428571429, 
4.19047619047619, 3.83741496598639), `Column 4` = c(4.375, 4.43333333333333, 
4.375, 3.5, 3.75, 4.08333333333333, 4.30952380952381, 3.25, 5, 
4.9375, 4.875, 3.88333333333333, 4.25, 4.4375, 4.27083333333333, 
3.58333333333333, 3.625, 3.275, 4.08333333333333, 4.05), `Column 5` = c(5, 
4.27777777777778, 4.44444444444444, 3.5, 4.5, 3.77777777777778, 
4.38095238095238, 4.16666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.91666666666667, 
5, 4.13333333333333, 4.55555555555556, 4.66666666666667, 4.65, 
4.33333333333333, 4.44444444444444, 3.26666666666667, 4.77777777777778, 
4.3), `Column 6` = c(4.33333333333333, 4.5, 4.52222222222222, 
4, 3.83333333333333, 4, 4.52380952380952, 4.16666666666667, 4.55555555555556, 
4.91666666666667, 4.36111111111111, 4, 4, 4.91666666666667, 4.41666666666667, 
4, 3.33333333333333, 4.08333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4.06666666666667
), `Column 7` = c(4.11538461538461, 4.18461538461538, 4.46153846153846, 
3.92307692307692, 3.72727272727273, 4.11666666666667, 3.68131868131868, 
3.55128205128205, 4.70512820512821, 4.71153846153846, 4.69871794871795, 
3.93333333333333, 4, 4.61538461538461, 4.37121212121212, 3.75925925925926, 
3.80555555555556, 3.70512820512821, 4.43589743589744, 4.01813186813187
), `Column 8` = c(4, 4.05833333333333, 4.70833333333333, 3.875, 
4.25, 4.16666666666667, 3.96428571428571, 2.9375, 4.70833333333333, 
4.6875, 4.875, 3.8375, 4.33333333333333, 4.1875, 4.6, 4.16666666666667, 
3.58333333333333, 3.5625, 4.16666666666667, 3.96706349206349), 
    `Column 9` = c(4.4, 4.33333333333333, 4.6, 4.1, 3.8, 4.06666666666667, 
    4.37142857142857, 3.9, 4.73333333333333, 4.9, 4.75, 4.28, 
    4.06666666666667, 4.75, 4.56, 3.4, 3.26666666666667, 3.56, 
    4.33333333333333, 4.00444444444444), `Column 10` = c(4, 4.22777777777778, 
    4.45555555555556, 3.7, 3.8, 4, 4.26587301587302, 3.91666666666667, 
    4.94444444444444, 4.79166666666667, 4.81944444444444, 3.7, 
    4.11111111111111, 4.61111111111111, 4.88888888888889, 4.25, 
    4.25, 4.08888888888889, 4.19444444444444, 4.43234126984127
    ), `Column 11` = c(4.33333333333333, 4.05555555555556, 4.5, 
    4.16666666666667, 3.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.83333333333333, 4.77777777777778, 4.91666666666667, 4.5, 
    3.9, 3.88888888888889, 4.75, 4.6, 3.22222222222222, 3.44444444444444, 
    3.8, 4.33333333333333, 4.11666666666667), `Column 12` = c(4.16666666666667, 
    4.27777777777778, 4.5, 3.25, 4.5, 3.83333333333333, 4, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.61111111111111, 4.66666666666667, 4.83333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 
    3.88888888888889, 4.36111111111111, 4.13888888888889, 4, 
    4.88888888888889, 3.91666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.005291005291
    ), `Column 13` = c(4.22222222222222, 4.27777777777778, 4.43518518518519, 
    4.05555555555556, 4.125, 4.31481481481481, 3.63227513227513, 
    3.58333333333333, 4.88888888888889, 4.72222222222222, 4.84259259259259, 
    4.07777777777778, 4.2962962962963, 4.69444444444444, 4.40625, 
    3.97916666666667, 4.11111111111111, 3.825, 4.31481481481481, 
    4.08086419753086), `Column 14` = c(4.11111111111111, 4.22962962962963, 
    4.3, 3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 4.07407407407407, 
    3.94179894179894, 3.80555555555556, 4.88888888888889, 4.69444444444444, 
    4.75925925925926, 3.80740740740741, 3.98148148148148, 4.72222222222222, 
    4.5, 3.66666666666667, 3.35185185185185, 3.82592592592593, 
    4.22222222222222, 4.18302469135802), `Column 15` = c(4.125, 
    4.55833333333333, 4.59166666666667, 4, 4.25, 4, 4.39285714285714, 
    4, 5, 4.9375, 4.9375, 4.35833333333333, 4.16666666666667, 
    4.9375, 5, 4.45833333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4.75, 4.75, 
    4.52916666666667), `Column 16` = c(4.21428571428571, 4.31428571428571, 
    4.5047619047619, 3.85714285714286, 4.08333333333333, 4.26190476190476, 
    3.90068027210884, 3.53571428571429, 4.90476190476191, 4.89285714285714, 
    4.89285714285714, 3.87222222222222, 4.33333333333333, 4.71428571428571, 
    4.61944444444444, 4.25, 4.14285714285714, 3.51111111111111, 
    4.23809523809524, 4.28174603174603), `Column 17` = c(NaN, 
    1.02777777777778, NaN, 1.17142857142857, 2.07142857142857, 
    1.52777777777778, 1.11111111111111, 1.27777777777778, NaN, 
    1, 1.11428571428571, 1.32258064516129, 1.78125, 1.52777777777778, 
    1.69444444444444, 2.05714285714286, 1.48571428571429, 2.22222222222222, 
    NaN, 1.38235294117647), `Topic 1` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Topic 2` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), 
    `Topic 3` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1), `Topic 4` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `Topic 5` = c(1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), `Topic 6` = c(1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
    `Topic 7` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Topic 8` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Data overview**

There are 17 columns named Column 1 through Column 17, and 8 columns named Topic 1 through Topic 8. There are actually over 15k rows, but for simplicity I've only sampled 20 rows.

```
Rows: 20
Columns: 25
$ `Column 1`  <dbl> 4.687500, 4.356250, 4.620833, 3.625000, 4.125000, 4.166667, 4.410714,...
$ `Column 2`  <dbl> 4.166667, 4.200000, 3.388889, 4.000000, 3.333333, 4.066667, 3.878571,...
$ `Column 3`  <dbl> 4.428571, 4.295238, 4.576190, 3.642857, 4.000000, 4.261905, 3.642177,...
$ `Column 4`  <dbl> 4.375000, 4.433333, 4.375000, 3.500000, 3.750000, 4.083333, 4.309524,...
$ `Column 5`  <dbl> 5.000000, 4.277778, 4.444444, 3.500000, 4.500000, 3.777778, 4.380952,...
$ `Column 6`  <dbl> 4.333333, 4.500000, 4.522222, 4.000000, 3.833333, 4.000000, 4.523810,...
$ `Column 7`  <dbl> 4.115385, 4.184615, 4.461538, 3.923077, 3.727273, 4.116667, 3.681319,...
$ `Column 8`  <dbl> 4.000000, 4.058333, 4.708333, 3.875000, 4.250000, 4.166667, 3.964286,...
$ `Column 9`  <dbl> 4.400000, 4.333333, 4.600000, 4.100000, 3.800000, 4.066667, 4.371429,...
$ `Column 10` <dbl> 4.000000, 4.227778, 4.455556, 3.700000, 3.800000, 4.000000, 4.265873,...
$ `Column 11` <dbl> 4.333333, 4.055556, 4.500000, 4.166667, 3.833333, 4.333333, 4.714286,...
$ `Column 12` <dbl> 4.166667, 4.277778, 4.500000, 3.250000, 4.500000, 3.833333, 4.000000,...
$ `Column 13` <dbl> 4.222222, 4.277778, 4.435185, 4.055556, 4.125000, 4.314815, 3.632275,...
$ `Column 14` <dbl> 4.111111, 4.229630, 4.300000, 3.833333, 3.833333, 4.074074, 3.941799,...
$ `Column 15` <dbl> 4.125000, 4.558333, 4.591667, 4.000000, 4.250000, 4.000000, 4.392857,...
$ `Column 16` <dbl> 4.214286, 4.314286, 4.504762, 3.857143, 4.083333, 4.261905, 3.900680,...
$ `Column 17` <dbl> NaN, 1.027778, NaN, 1.171429, 2.071429, 1.527778, 1.111111, 1.277778,...
$ `Topic 1`   <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ `Topic 2`   <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ `Topic 3`   <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1
$ `Topic 4`   <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
$ `Topic 5`   <dbl> 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
$ `Topic 6`   <dbl> 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
$ `Topic 7`   <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ `Topic 8`   <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Column 1 through Column 17 in rows and Topic 1 to Topic 8 as columns with sub columns `1` and `0`, and I'd like to have N, mean (std), median (IQR) for each group in topics. like the following;

[image]

I'm struggling with this a bit. I used to use `TableOne` package in R, but I can't figure out how to get the subgroup as well.

The closest I could do was using CreateTableOne, but still doesn't give me the way I wanted.

```
df.long <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols= "Topic 1":"Topic 8", names_to="Topics", values_to="state")

tabs <- CreateTableOne(vars = comps, strata = c("Topics", "state"), data = df.long)

print(tabs,nonnormal=T )
```

I get this but not what I"m looking for. Please note that it stratifies by Topic and state but doesn't put them together for each Topic as I'm looking for.

```
                        Stratified by Topics:state
                           Topic 1:0         Topic 2:0         Topic 3:0        
  n                          10                13                14             
  Column 1 (median [IQR])  4.29 [4.04, 4.55] 4.45 [4.12, 4.75] 4.39 [4.03, 4.73]
  Column 2 (median [IQR])  3.71 [3.43, 4.12] 4.17 [3.58, 4.67] 4.03 [3.60, 4.59]
  Column 3 (median [IQR])  4.17 [3.90, 4.51] 4.32 [4.10, 4.58] 4.29 [4.15, 4.57]
  Column 4 (median [IQR])  4.17 [3.73, 4.42] 4.38 [4.05, 4.44] 4.26 [3.93, 4.42]
  Column 5 (median [IQR])  4.44 [4.31, 4.72] 4.56 [4.44, 4.67] 4.60 [4.24, 4.75]
  Column 6 (median [IQR])  4.21 [4.02, 4.47] 4.36 [4.00, 4.52] 4.33 [4.00, 4.50]
  Column 7 (median [IQR])  4.10 [3.85, 4.46] 4.18 [4.00, 4.62] 4.24 [3.95, 4.58]
  Column 8 (median [IQR])  4.17 [3.99, 4.60] 4.25 [4.00, 4.69] 4.22 [4.04, 4.67]
  Column 9 (median [IQR])  4.20 [3.67, 4.53] 4.40 [4.07, 4.73] 4.37 [4.07, 4.70]
  Column 10 (median [IQR]) 4.25 [4.20, 4.45] 4.43 [4.11, 4.79] 4.15 [3.94, 4.75]
  Column 11 (median [IQR]) 4.09 [3.82, 4.46] 4.33 [4.06, 4.60] 4.33 [3.97, 4.57]
  Column 12 (median [IQR]) 4.39 [4.00, 4.67] 4.36 [4.14, 4.61] 4.43 [4.15, 4.65]
  Column 13 (median [IQR]) 4.29 [4.09, 4.41] 4.30 [4.12, 4.69] 4.31 [4.15, 4.63]
  Column 14 (median [IQR]) 4.20 [3.86, 4.28] 4.23 [3.98, 4.69] 4.17 [3.87, 4.65]
  Column 15 (median [IQR]) 4.63 [4.54, 4.75] 4.59 [4.25, 4.94] 4.47 [4.14, 4.94]
  Column 16 (median [IQR]) 4.30 [4.24, 4.46] 4.33 [4.21, 4.71] 4.30 [4.12, 4.69]
  Column 17 (median [IQR]) 1.43 [1.09, 1.85] 1.43 [1.13, 1.65] 1.43 [1.20, 1.65]
                          Stratified by Topics:state
                           Topic 4:0         Topic 5:0         Topic 6:0        
  n                          11                 6                10             
  Column 1 (median [IQR])  4.18 [3.82, 4.70] 4.15 [4.03, 4.31] 4.38 [4.19, 4.67]
  Column 2 (median [IQR])  3.67 [3.39, 4.17] 3.56 [3.43, 4.05] 4.13 [3.91, 4.59]
  Column 3 (median [IQR])  4.19 [3.68, 4.56] 4.07 [3.61, 4.26] 4.28 [3.94, 4.48]
  Column 4 (median [IQR])  3.88 [3.54, 4.41] 4.00 [3.39, 4.39] 4.29 [4.06, 4.44]
  Column 5 (median [IQR])  4.44 [4.15, 4.67] 4.39 [4.19, 4.54] 4.34 [4.17, 4.66]
  Column 6 (median [IQR])  4.17 [4.00, 4.54] 4.12 [4.02, 4.31] 4.39 [4.02, 4.52]
  Column 7 (median [IQR])  3.93 [3.78, 4.54] 3.86 [3.71, 4.14] 4.15 [3.95, 4.55]
  Column 8 (median [IQR])  4.17 [3.71, 4.44] 4.15 [3.69, 4.31] 4.11 [3.96, 4.50]
  Column 9 (median [IQR])  4.28 [3.73, 4.67] 3.98 [3.82, 4.27] 4.35 [4.14, 4.69]
  Column 10 (median [IQR]) 4.25 [4.00, 4.53] 4.10 [3.96, 4.20] 4.35 [4.06, 4.77]
  Column 11 (median [IQR]) 4.17 [3.82, 4.62] 3.86 [3.83, 4.01] 4.42 [4.13, 4.69]
  Column 12 (median [IQR]) 4.50 [4.17, 4.67] 4.31 [4.01, 4.46] 4.21 [4.00, 4.55]
  Column 13 (median [IQR]) 4.11 [4.02, 4.56] 4.20 [3.90, 4.29] 4.30 [4.08, 4.62]
  Column 14 (median [IQR]) 3.83 [3.81, 4.50] 3.91 [3.83, 4.17] 4.21 [3.97, 4.67]
  Column 15 (median [IQR]) 4.67 [4.41, 4.84] 4.40 [4.19, 4.70] 4.54 [4.37, 4.94]
  Column 16 (median [IQR]) 4.24 [3.86, 4.61] 4.20 [3.67, 4.33] 4.30 [3.99, 4.69]
  Column 17 (median [IQR]) 1.40 [1.25, 1.66] 1.53 [1.16, 2.00] 1.32 [1.11, 1.53]
                          Stratified by Topics:state
                           Topic 7:0         Topic 8:0         Topic 1:1        
  n                          11                 5                10             
  Column 1 (median [IQR])  4.17 [3.90, 4.29] 4.12 [4.00, 4.45] 4.29 [3.92, 4.63]
  Column 2 (median [IQR])  3.67 [3.47, 3.87] 3.58 [3.33, 4.67] 4.03 [3.72, 4.30]
  Column 3 (median [IQR])  4.10 [3.68, 4.21] 4.14 [4.00, 4.32] 4.25 [3.73, 4.40]
  Column 4 (median [IQR])  4.05 [3.60, 4.17] 4.25 [3.75, 4.27] 4.18 [3.78, 4.36]
  Column 5 (median [IQR])  4.33 [3.96, 4.44] 4.56 [4.50, 4.65] 4.44 [4.14, 4.66]
  Column 6 (median [IQR])  4.00 [4.00, 4.21] 4.00 [4.00, 4.42] 4.25 [4.00, 4.50]
  Column 7 (median [IQR])  3.93 [3.78, 4.07] 4.00 [3.76, 4.37] 4.02 [3.78, 4.31]
  Column 8 (median [IQR])  3.97 [3.86, 4.17] 4.33 [4.25, 4.60] 4.08 [3.90, 4.23]
  Column 9 (median [IQR])  4.07 [3.78, 4.31] 4.07 [3.80, 4.56] 4.33 [4.07, 4.52]
  Column 10 (median [IQR]) 4.19 [4.04, 4.26] 4.25 [4.11, 4.79] 4.00 [3.83, 4.52]
  Column 11 (median [IQR]) 4.12 [3.84, 4.33] 3.89 [3.83, 4.60] 4.33 [3.97, 4.69]
  Column 12 (median [IQR]) 4.00 [3.90, 4.58] 4.14 [4.00, 4.50] 4.25 [4.03, 4.47]
  Column 13 (median [IQR]) 4.08 [4.02, 4.31] 4.30 [4.12, 4.41] 4.17 [4.06, 4.38]
  Column 14 (median [IQR]) 3.94 [3.82, 4.13] 3.98 [3.83, 4.50] 4.01 [3.83, 4.40]
  Column 15 (median [IQR]) 4.46 [4.26, 4.63] 4.46 [4.25, 4.94] 4.30 [4.03, 4.80]
  Column 16 (median [IQR]) 4.24 [3.89, 4.27] 4.33 [4.25, 4.62] 4.15 [3.88, 4.53]
  Column 17 (median [IQR]) 1.49 [1.32, 1.78] 1.78 [1.69, 2.06] 1.43 [1.25, 1.57]
                          Stratified by Topics:state
                           Topic 2:1         Topic 3:1         Topic 4:1        
  n                           7                 6                 9             
  Column 1 (median [IQR])  4.17 [3.82, 4.26] 4.22 [4.01, 4.33] 4.36 [4.17, 4.45]
  Column 2 (median [IQR])  3.67 [3.47, 3.87] 3.69 [2.99, 3.87] 4.07 [3.84, 4.20]
  Column 3 (median [IQR])  3.71 [3.56, 4.21] 3.78 [3.66, 4.03] 4.26 [4.00, 4.32]
  Column 4 (median [IQR])  3.88 [3.43, 4.08] 3.84 [3.59, 4.24] 4.27 [4.08, 4.38]
  Column 5 (median [IQR])  4.17 [3.96, 4.36] 4.32 [4.28, 4.37] 4.50 [4.30, 4.65]
  Column 6 (median [IQR])  4.08 [4.00, 4.25] 4.07 [4.02, 4.40] 4.33 [4.00, 4.42]
  Column 7 (median [IQR])  3.76 [3.69, 4.03] 3.78 [3.72, 3.96] 4.12 [4.00, 4.18]
  Column 8 (median [IQR])  3.96 [3.70, 4.17] 3.97 [3.68, 4.04] 4.17 [4.00, 4.33]
  Column 9 (median [IQR])  4.07 [3.73, 4.31] 3.78 [3.44, 4.25] 4.33 [4.07, 4.40]
  Column 10 (median [IQR]) 4.09 [3.96, 4.22] 4.25 [4.23, 4.26] 4.23 [4.00, 4.43]
  Column 11 (median [IQR]) 3.90 [3.82, 4.33] 3.93 [3.53, 4.10] 4.33 [4.06, 4.50]
  Column 12 (median [IQR]) 4.00 [3.96, 4.50] 4.00 [4.00, 4.21] 4.14 [4.00, 4.28]
  Column 13 (median [IQR]) 3.98 [3.73, 4.20] 4.03 [3.86, 4.10] 4.28 [4.12, 4.31]
  Column 14 (median [IQR]) 3.83 [3.81, 4.01] 3.88 [3.71, 4.12] 4.11 [3.98, 4.23]
  Column 15 (median [IQR]) 4.39 [4.18, 4.60] 4.54 [4.48, 4.64] 4.39 [4.17, 4.56]
  Column 16 (median [IQR]) 3.90 [3.70, 4.24] 4.20 [3.96, 4.27] 4.28 [4.21, 4.33]
  Column 17 (median [IQR]) 1.43 [1.29, 1.92] 1.43 [1.18, 1.91] 1.46 [1.11, 1.72]
                          Stratified by Topics:state
                           Topic 5:1         Topic 6:1         Topic 7:1        
  n                          14                10                 9             
  Column 1 (median [IQR])  4.37 [4.01, 4.67] 4.15 [3.97, 4.55] 4.69 [4.36, 4.77]
  Column 2 (median [IQR])  3.94 [3.71, 4.30] 3.47 [3.35, 3.80] 4.35 [4.17, 4.67]
  Column 3 (median [IQR])  4.25 [3.90, 4.51] 4.12 [3.79, 4.37] 4.43 [4.30, 4.58]
  Column 4 (median [IQR])  4.18 [3.92, 4.38] 3.92 [3.59, 4.34] 4.43 [4.27, 4.88]
  Column 5 (median [IQR])  4.44 [4.31, 4.67] 4.47 [4.36, 4.72] 4.67 [4.50, 4.92]
  Column 6 (median [IQR])  4.33 [4.00, 4.52] 4.12 [4.00, 4.33] 4.42 [4.33, 4.56]
  Column 7 (median [IQR])  4.12 [3.93, 4.46] 3.90 [3.74, 4.36] 4.37 [4.12, 4.70]
  Column 8 (median [IQR])  4.17 [3.96, 4.50] 4.17 [3.69, 4.31] 4.25 [4.06, 4.69]
  Column 9 (median [IQR])  4.35 [4.07, 4.59] 3.98 [3.62, 4.38] 4.56 [4.33, 4.75]
  Column 10 (median [IQR]) 4.26 [4.05, 4.57] 4.15 [4.02, 4.25] 4.61 [4.00, 4.82]
  Column 11 (median [IQR]) 4.33 [4.13, 4.69] 3.86 [3.81, 4.33] 4.50 [4.06, 4.75]
  Column 12 (median [IQR]) 4.26 [4.00, 4.65] 4.42 [4.04, 4.62] 4.36 [4.28, 4.61]
  Column 13 (median [IQR]) 4.27 [4.08, 4.43] 4.17 [4.01, 4.31] 4.41 [4.22, 4.72]
  Column 14 (median [IQR]) 4.15 [3.86, 4.45] 3.91 [3.81, 4.19] 4.50 [4.11, 4.72]
  Column 15 (median [IQR]) 4.56 [4.37, 4.89] 4.53 [4.19, 4.73] 4.94 [4.25, 4.94]
  Column 16 (median [IQR]) 4.26 [4.16, 4.59] 4.23 [4.10, 4.31] 4.62 [4.21, 4.89]
  Column 17 (median [IQR]) 1.43 [1.21, 1.53] 1.78 [1.38, 2.06] 1.28 [1.07, 1.61]
                          Stratified by Topics:state
                           Topic 8:1         p      test    SMD   
  n                          15                                   
  Column 1 (median [IQR])  4.33 [4.06, 4.65]  0.641 nonnorm  0.372
  Column 2 (median [IQR])  3.88 [3.60, 4.18]  0.093 nonnorm  0.512
  Column 3 (median [IQR])  4.23 [3.74, 4.48]  0.291 nonnorm  0.420
  Column 4 (median [IQR])  4.08 [3.75, 4.40]  0.422 nonnorm  0.413
  Column 5 (median [IQR])  4.38 [4.15, 4.67]  0.365 nonnorm  0.418
  Column 6 (median [IQR])  4.33 [4.03, 4.51]  0.904 nonnorm  0.306
  Column 7 (median [IQR])  4.12 [3.86, 4.45]  0.403 nonnorm  0.434
  Column 8 (median [IQR])  4.00 [3.86, 4.18]  0.314 nonnorm  0.439
  Column 9 (median [IQR])  4.33 [4.04, 4.50]  0.283 nonnorm  0.471
  Column 10 (median [IQR]) 4.23 [4.00, 4.44]  0.856 nonnorm  0.352
  Column 11 (median [IQR]) 4.33 [3.98, 4.50]  0.272 nonnorm  0.434
  Column 12 (median [IQR]) 4.33 [4.00, 4.64]  0.943 nonnorm  0.251
  Column 13 (median [IQR]) 4.22 [4.07, 4.38]  0.299 nonnorm  0.460
  Column 14 (median [IQR]) 4.11 [3.83, 4.26]  0.261 nonnorm  0.456
  Column 15 (median [IQR]) 4.56 [4.24, 4.75]  0.936 nonnorm  0.285
  Column 16 (median [IQR]) 4.24 [3.89, 4.41]  0.371 nonnorm  0.463
  Column 17 (median [IQR]) 1.32 [1.14, 1.51]  0.974 nonnorm  0.327
```

So, to re-iterate, I'd like a couple of things in the table.

1. Columns 1: Columns 8 as Rows
2. Topic 1: Topic 8 as Column
3. N for each topic and sub-topic
4. mean(std)
5. median(iqr)
6. For each Column, I also want a statistical test. perhaps kruskal-wallis test? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the information in the correct structure.  (The `sub_topic` column is just the long form of your wide-form representation.)

You can perform whatever statistical tests you need once you have the `state` values specified per column and topic.

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols= "Column 1":"Column 17", 
               names_to = "column", 
               names_pattern = " (\\d+)$",
               values_to = "state") %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(column, state), 
               names_to = "topic",
               names_pattern = " (\\d+)$",
               values_to = "sub_topic") %>%
  group_by(topic, sub_topic, column) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            m = mean(state),
            std = sd(state),
            median = median(state),
            iqr = IQR(state, na.rm = T)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(column, topic, sub_topic)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = topic, names_prefix = "topic_", values_from = value) %>%
  arrange(column, sub_topic) %>%
  select(column, sub_topic, name, everything())
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 170 x 11
# Groups:   sub_topic [2]
   column sub_topic name   topic_1 topic_2 topic_3 topic_4 topic_5 topic_6 topic_7 topic_8
   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 1              0 n       10      13      14      11       6      10      11       5    
 2 1              0 m        4.30    4.41    4.35    4.22    4.20    4.34    4.10    4.23 
 3 1              0 std      0.380   0.393   0.424   0.482   0.331   0.388   0.310   0.471
 4 1              0 median   4.29    4.45    4.39    4.18    4.15    4.38    4.17    4.12 
 5 1              0 iqr      0.510   0.625   0.703   0.880   0.281   0.485   0.391   0.448
 6 1              1 n       10       7       6       9      14      10       9      15    
 7 1              1 m        4.26    4.06    4.14    4.36    4.32    4.23    4.51    4.30 
 8 1              1 std      0.422   0.289   0.280   0.251   0.421   0.407   0.370   0.378
 9 1              1 median   4.29    4.17    4.22    4.36    4.37    4.15    4.69    4.33 
10 1              1 iqr      0.709   0.441   0.318   0.281   0.660   0.580   0.415   0.592
# … with 160 more rows
```

Steps:

1. pivot columns to long
2. pivot topics/sub-topics to long
3. group by topic->sub_topic->column, perform aggregations
4. more pivoting to get topics to wide again
5. arrange row and column order

Comment: This is a great attempt but not quite what I'm looking for. The sub topics should come next to each other below the topic as shown in the figure in the original question

Comment: What you are describing is actually how the output in this solution is structured.  What you have drawn as sub topics next to each other as multi-index columns is not formally different than the way they're represented here - it's just that they are in tidy format this way.  All of the calculations you need to do are available to you with this solution.  If you're asking for help with cosmetic formatting of the resulting data, that feels like a separate question - it's a different technical topic from the rectangling procedure.

Comment: Understood. This is good for me to get to this point. I think this gives me an idea to figure out the rest.